# How to stop Netflix playing next episode automatically?

Tags: netflix

I'm watching Arrested Development on Netflix. It cuts the last 30 seconds of each video and starts playing episode. I don't want that. I'd rather it played to the end of the video and STOPPED. How can I get that?

Comment: Is this for watching in the web app?

Comment: Yeah I'm watching on a computer in a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know when it was added, but there is now a control for "Autoplay" in the right sidebar.

[image: Autoplay ON]

---

[image: Autoplay OFF]

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you want to stop ANY show from playing the next episode automatically, you can now turn it off in your account preferences.

Hover over your profile name in the top right, click *Your Account*, then find your profile settings and click *Playback settings*. Uncheck **Play next episode automatically** and it will never happen to you again on that profile.

I'm pretty sure this setting has to be changes individually for each profile if you want this behavior on other profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Just drag the bottom edge of the current episode still playing to the bottom of the iPad screen, covering the "next episode playing in" area.  The current episode will then keep playing until the end.

Answer (score -1):

On Desktop: If you're in fullscreen mode, pressing escape to get out of fullscreen will stop the auto-play.