# While other windows are active, is there a way to disable the "continue playing" feature of Netflix?

Tags: netflix

After so long, I am prompted to click a button to prove that I haven't gone idle.  This is an inconvenience to me, especially if I am watching Netflix on one monitor and gaming on another. For example, when playing Skyrim, <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>-ing can cause the game to crash.  Surely, someone has come up with a way to trick Netflix by fauxing activity to make it appear as though I am not immersed in something else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stop Netflix playing next episode automatically?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/45430/how-to-stop-netflix-playing-next-episode-automatically)

Comment: To me, those looks like separate issues. This one is about a Netflix message popping up when Netflix is not the top-most window, while the other is about another playback issue.

Comment: Yes, you can, copy/paste this into the JS console once your video starts playing: https://gist.github.com/coopermaruyama/2a704d13debb4e89adda

Comment: @CooperMaruyama  Thanks, looks promising.  However, over the past year, I haven't been prompted with this.  Unless I haven't been binge-watching like I used to, it's almost as if Netflix disabled this.

Comment: I binge watch and I definitely still get it all the time.

Comment: This is pretty old, but I believe this application for chrome is what you're looking for: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/netflix-pause-removal/mfekcpndbpdgjjfahekhncdfegkhbghg There is also a bookmartlet in the github page if you aren't using chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This feature can now be disabled. See the help article at:

https://help.netflix.com/en/node/2102

Comment: I don't believe this solves the problem, this only disables the screen that appears after watching movie/episode, "Post-play".